ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2233188 into shape (123,)
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # for creating plots
import numpy as np  # for mathematical operations
import time  # to calculate consumption time
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file  # loading the a8a and a8a.t datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler #
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split # to split the data
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score # to measure the accuracy
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix # scipy model to take care of sparse matrix(ensure the matrix is sparse)
Specify the data directory
Check if 'data' directory exists, if not, create it
data_dir = 'data'
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
os.makedirs(data_dir)
Download the datasets if they don't exist
You might need to adjust the URL based on where the datasets are hosted
a8a_url = "https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary/a8a"
a8a_t_url = "https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/binary/a8a.t"
a8a_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'a8a')
a8a_t_path = os.path.join(data_dir, 'a8a.t')
import urllib.request  # For downloading the files
if not os.path.exists(a8a_path):
urllib.request.urlretrieve(a8a_url, a8a_path)
print(f"Downloaded 'a8a' dataset to {a8a_path}")
if not os.path.exists(a8a_t_path):
urllib.request.urlretrieve(a8a_t_url, a8a_t_path)
print(f"Downloaded 'a8a.t' dataset to {a8a_t_path}")
Load training and testing datasets
X, y = load_svmlight_file(os.path.join(data_dir, 'a8a'))  # Training dataset
X_test, y_test = load_svmlight_file(os.path.join(data_dir, 'a8a.t'))  # Testing dataset
Ensure y is a column vector
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
y_test = y_test.reshape(-1, 1)  # Ensure consistency for the test set
Split the data into training and validation sets
Use X and y which are already loaded and defined
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
Get dimensions from the training set
n, d = X.shape # The number of training samples(22696) and the features(dimension)(123)
w0 = np.zeros(d) # initial value of w0, have the same dimension as d
Algorithm parameters
lambda_ = 0.01 # regularization parameter
eta0 = 0.01 #learning rate described under algorithm 2
alpha = 0.1 #hypergradient learning rate described under algorithm 2
m = 15  # Inner loop size(iteration)
n_iters = 30  # Outer loop size(epoch)
batch_sizes = [300, 400, 500, 600]  # Mini-batch sizes to test
Loss function describe by Zhang in Section 5 "Numerical results"
def loss(w, X, y, lambda_):
z = X.dot(w)
return np.log(1 + np.exp(-y*z)) + (lambda_ / 2) * np.linalg.norm(w)**2
Gradient of the loss function
def grad_loss(w, y, X, lambda_):
z = X @ w # matrix multiplication
y = y.flatten()  # Ensure y is 1D
return -( X.T * y) @ (1 / (1 + np.exp(z * y))) + lambda_*w
Full gradient computation is given under Algorithm 2
def full_grad(w, y, X, lambda_):
n = X.shape[0]
z = X @ w  # This works for sparse matrices
# Reshape y to ensure it's a column vector and avoid broadcasting issues
y = y.reshape(-1, 1)
exp_term = y / (1 + np.exp(y * z))
grad = (X.T @ exp_term) / n + lambda_ * w.reshape(-1, 1)  # Reshape w to (123, 1)
# Reshape grad back to the original shape of w if needed
grad = grad[:123] # Reshape grad to the shape of w (123,)
return grad
def SFR_SARAH_HD(X_train, y_train, n_iters, eta0, batch_size):
n, d = X_train.shape  # Use X_train here
w0 = np.zeros(d)  # Initialize weights
# Use y_train instead of y
z0 = full_grad(w0, y_train, X_train, lambda_)  # Use X_train here
total_time = 0 # The time set to zero
for outer_iter in range(n_iters):
    start = time.perf_counter()
    indices = np.random.permutation(n)
    X_shuffled = X_train[indices]  # Create a shuffled copy of X_train
    v0 = z0
    d0 = -v0
    grad_eta_delta = 0

    for k in range(m):
        # Reshape d0 to match w0 before performing the operation
        # Ensure d0 has the correct number of elements for reshaping
        d0_reshaped = d0.reshape(w0.shape) if d0.shape != w0.shape else d0
        w = w0 + eta0 * d0_reshaped
        mini_batch = np.random.choice(n, size=batch_size, replace=False)

        # Assuming mini_batch_grad is defined elsewhere and expects a 1D array for w
        grad_w = mini_batch_grad(w, X_shuffled, y_train[indices], mini_batch) # Use X_shuffled and y_train[indices]
        grad_w0 = mini_batch_grad(w0, X_shuffled, y_train[indices], mini_batch) # Use X_shuffled and y_train[indices]

        h = grad_w * grad_eta_delta
        eta = abs(eta0 - alpha * h)
        v = grad_w - grad_w0 + v0
        beta = np.linalg.norm(v) ** 2 / np.linalg.norm(v0) ** 2
        d = -v + beta * d0
        v0 = v

    z0 = v0
    w0 = w

    end = time.perf_counter()
    total_time += (end - start)

return total_time

Testing for different mini-batch sizes
time_consume=[]
results = {}
for batch_size in batch_sizes:# this iterate over the mini-batches
print(f"Running SFR-SARAH-HD with mini-batch size: {batch_size}")
time_consumed = SFR_SARAH_HD(X_train, y_train, n_iters, eta0, batch_size)
results[batch_size] = time_consumed
print(f"Mini-batch size {batch_size}: Total time {time_consumed:.4f} seconds")
for outer_iter in range(n_iters): # this iterates over the epoch()
start_time=time.time()
time.sleep(1)
end_time = time.time()
time_taken = end_time-start_time
time_consume.append(time_taken)


I am trying to run the code, but i kept getting the error.
